# Unable to select nested array in JSON object with Microsoft Graph

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-rest-api, query, microsoft-graph, odata

Given the following Graph call response of `https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/sites/root:/sites/[siteTitle]:/lists/[listId]/Columns`, how can I only return/select down to the array "choices" that exists only in certain JSON objects?

```
{
"@odata.context": "https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/$metadata#Collection(microsoft.graph.list)('b2931a38-ee02-4f3a-8ba7-28f2defad033')/columns",
"value": [
    {
        "columnGroup": "[...]",
        "description": "",
        "displayName": "Titel",
        "enforceUniqueValues": false,
        "hidden": false,
        "id": "fa564e0f-0c70-4ab9-b863-0177e6ddd247",
        "indexed": false,
        "name": "Title",
        "readOnly": false,
        "required": true,
        "text": {
            "allowMultipleLines": false,
            "appendChangesToExistingText": false,
            "linesForEditing": 0,
            "maxLength": 255
        }
    },
    {
        "columnGroup": "[...]",
        "description": "",
        "displayName": "Complianceobjekt-ID",
        "enforceUniqueValues": false,
        "hidden": false,
        "id": "3a6b296c-3f50-445c-a13f-9c679ea9dda3",
        "indexed": false,
        "name": "ComplianceAssetId",
        "readOnly": true,
        "required": false,
        "text": {
            "allowMultipleLines": false,
            "appendChangesToExistingText": false,
            "linesForEditing": 0,
            "maxLength": 255
        }
    },
    {
        "columnGroup": "[...]",
        "description": "[...]",
        "displayName": "Description",
        "enforceUniqueValues": false,
        "hidden": false,
        "id": "cdf3465d-0500-453c-ad18-f2eaea265bdd",
        "indexed": false,
        "name": "[...]",
        "readOnly": false,
        "required": false,
        "text": {
            "allowMultipleLines": false,
            "appendChangesToExistingText": false,
            "linesForEditing": 0,
            "maxLength": 255
        }
    },
    {
        "columnGroup": "[...]",
        "description": "",
        "displayName": "Name of Requester",
        "enforceUniqueValues": false,
        "hidden": false,
        "id": "5c722dba-9406-4a2f-9798-06f040e528d9",
        "indexed": false,
        "name": "[...]",
        "readOnly": false,
        "required": false,
        "personOrGroup": {
            "allowMultipleSelection": false,
            "displayAs": "nameWithPresence",
            "chooseFromType": "peopleOnly"
        }
    },
    {
        "columnGroup": "[...]",
        "description": "",
        "displayName": "[...]",
        "enforceUniqueValues": false,
        "hidden": false,
        "id": "6415029c-d65d-4483-a287-0a45dc7b0ac3",
        "indexed": false,
        "name": "[...]",
        "readOnly": false,
        "required": true,
        "choice": {
            "allowTextEntry": false,
            "choices": [
                "BDS",
                "CDF",
                "DEV",
                "HR",
                "PM",
                "SER",
                "AM"
            ],
            "displayAs": "dropDownMenu"
        }
    },
}
```

I can do `https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/sites/root:/sites/[siteTitle]:/lists/[listId]/Columns?$select=choice` which gives me

```
{
"@odata.context": "https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/$metadata#Collection(microsoft.graph.list)('b2931a38-ee02-4f3a-8ba7-28f2defad033')/columns(choice)",
"value": [
    {},
    {},
    {},
    {},
    {
        "choice": {
            "allowTextEntry": false,
            "choices": [
                "BDS",
                "CDF",
                "DEV",
                "HR",
                "PM",
                "SER",
                "AM
            ],
            "displayAs": "dropDownMenu"
        }
    }
```

But I have not found a way to select down to the next level of "choices". `?select=choice/choices` gives

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": "BadRequest",
    "message": "Select options are not supported.",
    "innerError": {
      "request-id": "ef2508f2-c93c-48d8-89bf-7c03e6aa8dc3",
      "date": "2020-06-18T06:20:22"
    }
  }
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: I think `$expand` is not supported yet for `list/columns` endpoint.

Comment: I was afraid that that would be the case but couldn't find any info regarding this in the beta endpoint reference.

Comment: Yes, I too have not found anything related to this in documentation.